# Get a range of dates by interval

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-5.6

I need to generate a list of dates base on a date, interval and 60 days .
This is for partition maintenance task.
Nothing like an example:
`conf` table looks like:

```
schema tab  interval
--- --- ----
app tab1 daily
app tab2 monthly
app tab3 weekly
```

For simplicity, lets assume that joining it with information_schema will give each max partition date to `2020-05-17`.

```
select p.table_name, max(p.partition_description), max(pc. interval)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.partitions p
inner join conf pc
where  p.table_schema=pc.schema
  and p.partition_method='RANGE COLUMNS'
  and p.table_name=pc.tab
group by p.table_name;

result:
tab1 2020-05-18 daily
tab2 2020-06-01 monthly
tab3 2020-05-24 weekly
```

The query should return the tab name and all the dates from it's max date up to 60 days by the interval.
So, the result should look like:

```
tab  future_date
---  ---
tab2 2020-07-01
tab3 2020-05-31
tab3 2020-06-07
tab3 2020-06-14
tab3 2020-06-21
tab3 2020-06-28
tab3 2020-07-05
tab3 2020-07-12
tab1 2020-05-18
tab1 2020-05-19
tab1 2020-05-20
tab1 2020-05-21
..
tab1 2020-07-17
```

**EDIT**

A quick and dirty version would be union of the same select per interval on the max + 1 by the table interval and loop until there is no more rows. But it is ugly.

Comment: Just a suggestion: You can create a function to take, `interval`, `number of days`, `start` and `end dates`, and in that return all the dates for that info

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal but this is `bash` function that create the query dynamically and runs in a loop until there are no more results.

```
for INTERVAL in month week day ; do 
    NEW_PART="select concat('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p',replace(next_interval,'-',''), 
              ' VALUES LESS THAN (\'',next_interval,'\'));') 
            from (select p.table_schema,p.table_name, 
                  max(STR_TO_DATE(p.partition_description, '\'%Y-%m-%d\'')) + interval 1 ${INTERVAL} next_interval
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.partitions p
    inner join conf pc
    where  p.table_schema=pc.table_schema
      and p.partition_method='RANGE COLUMNS'
      and p.table_name=pc.table_name
      and lower(pc.partition_interval)='${INTERVAL}'
    group by p.table_name
    having max(STR_TO_DATE(p.partition_description, '\'%Y-%m-%d\'')) + interval 1 ${INTERVAL} < curdate() + interval 48 day) a"

    echo "${NEW_PART}" | ${MYSQL_CONN} > ${SCRIPT_SQL} 
    while [ `wc -l ${SCRIPT_SQL} | awk '{print $1}'` -gt 0 ]; do
            ${MYSQL_CONN} < ${SCRIPT_SQL} &>> ${SCRIPT_LOG}
            echo "${NEW_PART}" | ${MYSQL_CONN} > ${SCRIPT_SQL} 
    done
done
```